# How to submit this form in database using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the code that submits data in database. works fine .

How can I submit this form using jquery into database without refreshing the page.

Please help me with this code so i can understand the logic behind it and later use on my project.

**HTML**:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="reply"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="file" id="imgInp"/>
        <input   type="text" placeholder="say something" class="form-control" name="comment"/><br/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" name="submit">comment</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotwall") or die("unable to connect to internet");

$user = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$user'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

$user_id = $row['id'];
$user_name = $row['user_name'];
$post_slug = $row['post_slug'];  


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $con;
    global $user_id;
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/$post_image");
    $insert ="INSERT INTO comments (post_id, post_image, user_id, comment, author_name) VALUES ('$post_slug', '$post_image', '$user_id', '$comment', '$user_name')";

    $run = mysqli_query($con,$insert);
}
```

Comment: try ajax call of jquery

Comment: Refer [Ajax in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp).

Comment: You have a tendency of not attending to answers when people are answering your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick :)

```
$("form#reply").submit(function(){ // on form submit
    var vals = $(this).serialize(); // get all the form values

    $.ajax({
        url: "postpage.php", // page in which the php is
        method: "post",
        data: vals, // you can access the values in php like you normally 
                    // would (using the names of the individual input fields)
        success: function(){ // if post is successful
            alert("success!"); // alert "success!"
        }
    });

    return false; // prevent page refresh
});
```

You must put the **PHP** within a different file for it to actually work, however.

Answer (score 0):

On the button click/submit event hook up an jQuery ajax call.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save_the_form.php",
        data: {
          var1: value1,
          var2: value2,
        },
        success: function(feedback) {
          // DO SOMETHING
        }
    });
```

Then just configure your "save_the_form.php" file to do the database save and stuff and maybe throw some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It would basically be something like this using jQuery:

**jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: FORM_ACTION_PATH,
        data: {
          submit: {
            comment: value,
            file: value2
          }
        },
        success: function(retval) {
          // show success message
        }
    });
```

**Untested php code**:

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
          if ( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) && ! empty( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {

          handle_upload();

          }
    }

    function handle_upload () {
        global $con;
        global $user_id;
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/$post_image");
        $insert =" insert into comments (post_id,post_image,user_id,comment,author_name) values('$post_slug','$post_image','$user_id','$comment','$user_name' ) ";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$insert);

        return $run;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try like this. You need to submit your form with ajax and you are passing file with your form then you need to add some more parameter in ajax.

```
$("#submitAjax").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop page to refresh
  var formData = new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0]);
    $.ajax({
          url:'URL_OF_YOU_PHP_FILE',
          type:'POST',
          contentType: false,       
          cache: false,             
          processData:false,   
          data: formData,
          success:function(data){
            //Success 
            console.log(data);
        })
})
```

Change in you HTML button add `id` attribute

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="submitAjax" type="submit" name="submit">comment</button>
```